# \maketitle definition on article

Tags: titles, article, texdef

I am searching for the definition of `\maketitle` in the `article` class.

I searched on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base) but there is a lot of files. I don’t know in which one I can find this definition.

Comment: Really simple? `article.cls`

Comment: So, where can I find it?

Comment: Somewhere in your Tex-distribution. Try `kpsewhich article.cls` in a terminal.

Comment: Here is an online link to it: [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finaly find it on `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls` (Gentoo).

I use for that the command `kpsewhich article.cls`on a terminal.

Comment: the path is is also in the log file for every article class document that you process with latex.

Comment: If you use `bash` or `zsh`, `less $(kpsewhich article.cls)` avoids looking for the path. Thedefinition of `\maketitle` depends on whether you use the `titlepage` option or not.